# How to use LinkedHashMap to Concurrently write and Read

Tags: java, collections, plsql

Not able to read modified linkedHashMap simultaneously. How can i do the same job in a different way ! What i wanted to do is something of this kind !

```
while(flag) 
    for(String key:hashMap.keySet())
    {

        if(hashMap.get(key)==false)
        {
            hashMap.put(key,true);
            System.out.println(key+"\t\t\t:PACKAGE");
            String query="select REFERENCED_NAME from ALL_DEPENDENCIES where OWNER='xyz' AND REFERENCED_OWNER='xyz' AND NAME='"+key+"' AND TYPE='PACKAGE BODY' AND REFERENCED_TYPE='PACKAGE' AND REFERENCED_NAME<>'"+key+"'";
            ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()&&(rs.getString(1)!=key))
            {

                if((hashMap.get(rs.getString(1)) ==null) || !(hashMap.get(rs.getString(1))== true)){
                    hashMap.put(rs.getString(1),false);
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                }
            }
            //System.out.println("NEW :"+key);


            rs.close();
        }
    }

    flag=hashMap.containsValue(false);
    }
```

Comment: You are modifying the `hashmap` on the fly whose `keySet()` is being used for iteration. Java will not allow this. If you wish to do something similar, try to create a temporary `hashmap` and iterate over it's `keySet()` while you modify the original hashmap inside the loop.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't modify hashmap keys while iteration on the same. Have you considered using a temporary list or hashmap for modification ?

Comment: used a ConcurrentHashMap and it is done !

Answer (score 0):

used a ConcurrentHashMap and the problem is solved !